# How to get the toolbar to follow greybird theme in Corebird

Tags: xubuntu, greybird

I have Corebird installed and for some reason I can't figure out why the toolbar is differently colored. I am hoping that someone can help me to fix this. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official [site](http://corebird.baedert.org/), that's how it's supposed to look:

[image]

The actual toolbar is the toolbar/button controls combined one and it seems to be following your gtk3 theme correctly.

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping to find a way to edit the theme to make the toolbar icons light so they stand out like yours do in the picture. I will try editing the gtk3.